# How to determine the domain:port of a web application on ServletContextListener contextInitialized method?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jersey, servletcontextlistener

I need to know the domain:port of a web application made with JSP and Jersey on a Tomcat server.

I need to know it when the application starts, that is on `ServletContextListener contextInitialized()` method.

Is there a way to obtain it?

Comment: There can be many domains and many ports. That's why this information is provided in the request context, not the application context. The question has no meaning in the application context.

Comment: @halfer You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear.